# Entity Framework Many to Many Relationship object not available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im getting this error when adding a migration:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship
>   'Answer_1_API.Infrastructure.ApplicationUser_Companies' was not loaded
>   because the type 'Answer_1_API.Infrastructure.CompanyGroup' is not
>   available.

I modeled the Many-To-Many relationship loosely off this guide off [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#Model) article

**ApplicationUser:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<StartelClientGroup> AssignedClients { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CompanyGroup> Companies { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser() 
        {
            AssignedClients = new HashSet<StartelClientGroup>();
            Companies = new HashSet<CompanyGroup>();
        }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);

            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

**Group Classes:**

```
public class Group
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Members { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Group() 
        {
            Members = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
        }

    }

    public class CompanyGroup : Group
    {
        public CompanyGroup() : base() { }
    }

    public class StartelClientGroup : Group
    {
        public List<string> Values { get; set; }

        public Type ValueType { get; set; }

        public enum Type { ClientID, AccountNum, Affinity }

        public StartelClientGroup() : base() { }
    }
```

**DB Context:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) 
        {
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create() 
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public DbSet<StartelClientGroup> AssignedClients { get; set; }

        public DbSet<CompanyGroup> Companies { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>(); 
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

**Relation Configuration:**

```
public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserConfiguration() 
        {
            this.HasMany(x => x.Companies)
                .WithMany(x => x.Members);

            this.HasMany(x => x.AssignedClients)
                .WithMany(x => x.Members);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what im missing here?

Comment: see if this article helps you any .. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application  or this one  http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

Comment: How did you map the inheritance? Does each `Group` type have its own table? (TPC)

Comment: It absolutely did. I didnt think it was an inheritance issue but after removing and adding the migration it turned out it was. Thanks @JamieD77